# How can a vector have both contra-variant and co-variant components?

Tags: vectors, tensor-calculus

I have read that contra-variant and co-variat vectors have different transformation properties , which distinguish them, yet at the same time I have read that a vector can have contra-variant and co-variant components. If a vector can have contra-variant and co-variant components, then isn't this vector both contra-variant and co-variant? But isn't this impossible?

Comment: Co- and contravariant vectors are related by the [musical isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

Comment: contravariant and covariant vector is IMHO extremely bad terminology. A vector is just a vector, an arrow on a manifold pointing somewhere. We like to describe these objects by using numbers, hence we express vectors in terms of components. We can do this either in their original vector spaces, or by taking them to the dual space, whenever we have an object that allows us to do it in a more or less "standard" way (like a metric).

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105347/58382, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91593/58382, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37820/58382

Comment: @Phoenix87 I don't know, I think that description ignores the reason physical vectors are different from mathematical vectors, namely transformations.

Comment: @DavidZ: sorry, I don't get your comment

Comment: Bob, higher rank tensors have both co- and contra-variant components, e.g., $R^{\alpha}_{\beta \mu \nu}$, but I don't see how this is possible with a rank 1 tensor.